# Excel: Do nothing if cell is not blank else copy data from another cell

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I have an excel sheet that looks like this

```
     E       F 

             red
             yellow
     blue     
     green
```

I want to copy data from F column to E if E is not empty.

I came with a formula that looks like this:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E3));F3;"")
```

This works great for "red" and "yellow". However, craps out on "blue" and "green" and replaces those entry with empty cells.

Can someone help me in modifying the formula to suit my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a formula in a cell to copy another value to itself. What you want is a third column that copies the value from E if E is no blank, and otherwise copies the value from F.

So in column G:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E1),F1,E1)
```